# Java Scanner how to input string if function

Tags: java, string, if-statement, int

I am very new in programming into Java.

My question is that I have a code (see below) and I want to compare them with if statement. An errors occur at `line 9 (string test)` and `11(if(test.equals)`. I completely do not have idea.

I have made a code with int and it works perfect, but that.

```
package bucky;

import java.util.Scanner;

class apples {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String test = sc.nextLine();
        if (test.equals("YES")) {
            System.out.println("YES");
        } else {
            System.out.println("TIS IS ELSE");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What error? Please add the stacktrace or error-message.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there... define YES as string and that it

```
 String test = sc.nextLine();   
 String YES = "yes";   
 if (test.equals(YES)) {
```

or even better  use [equalsIgnoreCase](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String))() so you can get rid off the case sensitive input

```
 if (test.equalsIgnorecase(YES))
```

Comment: Sir method is `if (test.equalsIgnoreCase(YES))`